# How to generate a single path for a SVG using Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, svg, bitmap

This is the same question as [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25927/how-to-get-path-for-svg-with-illustrator-cs4), because that solution no longer seems to work.

I am using live trace on a Bitmap, and the results are good. When I go to save the document as SVG and click on "view SVG code", I'm given code with multiple paths.

Example:

```
<path class="st0" d="M132.7,288.7c0-40.9,0-81.7,0-122.6c44.8,0,89.7,0,134.6,0c0,40.9,0,81.7,0,122.6   C222.4,288.7,177.6,288.7,132.7,288.7z M152.5,259.9c0.8,0,1.2,0,1.6,0c2.5-0.3,4.9-0.5,7.4-0.8c3.9-0.6,7.9-1,11.8-0.2   c9,1.8,17.2,5.4,24.7,10.5c1,0.6,1.9,1.5,2.6,2.5c1.5,2.1,3.4,3,5.9,2.7c2.4-0.3,3.8-1.9,4.3-4.2c0.3-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-2.7   c3.7-2.8,7.8-4.3,12.3-4.8c5.9-0.6,11.9-1,17.8-1.7c8.2-0.9,14.2-5.4,18.3-12.4c0.6-1,0.4-1.3-0.8-1.3c-1.9,0-3.8,0-5.6-0.1   c-0.6,0-1.1-0.2-1.7-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3c0.4-0.3,0.7-0.5,1.1-0.8c1.4-0.9,2.9-1.7,4.3-2.6c3-2,4.4-4.8,4.9-8.3   c0.2-1.6-0.1-1.8-1.6-1.2c-1.2,0.5-2.3,1-3.5,1.5c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.5,0.4c0.5-0.7,0.8-1.2,1.1-1.6c1.1-1.5,2.3-2.9,3.4-4.3   c1.5-1.9,2.2-4.1,2.4-6.5c0-0.4-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.4c-0.5,0.1-1,0.1-1.4,0.3c-1.5,0.9-2.8,1.9-4.3,2.9c-2,1.3-3.1,1.2-4.8-0.4   c-0.5-0.5-0.9-1.1-1.3-1.7c-1.2-2.2-2.4-4.3-3.6-6.5c-1.5-2.8-2.2-2.5,1.5-3.9c3.9-1.5,6.7-4,8.3-7.8c2.6-6,3-12.3,2.5-18.8   c-0.1-0.7-0.2-1.4-0.2-2.2c-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.3c-4.1,2.5-8.7,3.6-13.4,4.1c-5.8,0.7-11,2.6-14.9,7.2c-1.3,1.5-1.4,1.5-3.1,0.5   c-6.1-3.6-12.7-5.6-19.7-6c-11.3-0.7-22,1.5-31.7,7.7c-1,0.6-1.6,0.5-2.2-0.4c-1.6-2-3.5-3.5-5.7-4.7c-2.8-1.5-5.8-2.1-8.8-2.6   c-5.4-1-10.7-2.1-15.6-4.8c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.3c-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.7-0.2,1c0,2.4-0.1,4.9-0.1,7.3c0.1,3.9,0.6,7.8,1.8,11.5   c1.7,5.3,4.9,9.1,10.2,11c0.9,0.3,1.8,0.8,2.6,1.1c1,0.4,1.4,0.9,0.8,2c-1.6,3.2-2.2,6.8-4.4,9.8c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3   c-1.4,4-4.3,6.7-8,8.5c-2.6,1.3-5.2,2.4-7.8,3.6c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.4-1.4,0.8c0.7,0.2,1.1,0.3,1.4,0.4c1.4,0.5,2.8,0.8,4.2,1.5   c2.6,1.3,5.1,2.2,8,1.9c0.3,0,0.7,0.3,1,0.4c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.8-0.6,0.9c-1.4,0.7-2.8,1.3-4.2,2c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.6-1.1,0.9   c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,1.1,1c2.5,1.5,5.2,1.9,8.1,1.7c0.7,0,1.3,0,2.4,0C155.5,255.1,154.1,257.3,152.5,259.9z"
       id="path7" /><path
       d="M152.5,259.9c1.6-2.6,2.9-4.8,4.5-7.4c-1.1,0-1.7,0-2.4,0c-2.9,0.2-5.6-0.2-8.1-1.7c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.7-1.1-1   c0.4-0.3,0.7-0.7,1.1-0.9c1.4-0.7,2.8-1.3,4.2-2c0.3-0.1,0.4-0.6,0.6-0.9c-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.4-1-0.4c-2.9,0.3-5.5-0.6-8-1.9   c-1.3-0.7-2.8-1-4.2-1.5c-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.2-1.4-0.4c0.6-0.4,1-0.6,1.4-0.8c2.6-1.2,5.3-2.3,7.8-3.6c3.7-1.8,6.6-4.5,8-8.5   c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c2.2-2.9,2.8-6.6,4.4-9.8c0.5-1.1,0.2-1.6-0.8-2c-0.9-0.3-1.8-0.8-2.6-1.1c-5.3-1.9-8.5-5.7-10.2-11   c-1.2-3.8-1.7-7.6-1.8-11.5c0-2.4,0.1-4.9,0.1-7.3c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-1c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3c4.9,2.7,10.2,3.8,15.6,4.8   c3,0.6,6,1.1,8.8,2.6c2.2,1.2,4.1,2.8,5.7,4.7c0.7,0.8,1.3,1,2.2,0.4c9.7-6.2,20.4-8.3,31.7-7.7c7,0.4,13.7,2.3,19.7,6   c1.7,1,1.8,1,3.1-0.5c3.9-4.6,9.1-6.6,14.9-7.2c4.7-0.5,9.3-1.6,13.4-4.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3c0.1,0.8,0.2,1.5,0.2,2.2   c0.5,6.4,0.1,12.8-2.5,18.8c-1.6,3.8-4.4,6.4-8.3,7.8c-3.7,1.4-3,1.1-1.5,3.9c1.2,2.2,2.3,4.4,3.6,6.5c0.3,0.6,0.8,1.2,1.3,1.7   c1.7,1.6,2.8,1.7,4.8,0.4c1.4-1,2.8-2,4.3-2.9c0.4-0.2,1-0.2,1.4-0.3c0.1,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.2,1.4c-0.2,2.4-0.9,4.6-2.4,6.5   c-1.1,1.5-2.3,2.9-3.4,4.3c-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.8-1.1,1.6c0.7-0.2,1.1-0.2,1.5-0.4c1.2-0.5,2.3-1,3.5-1.5c1.5-0.6,1.9-0.4,1.6,1.2   c-0.5,3.4-2,6.3-4.9,8.3c-1.4,0.9-2.9,1.8-4.3,2.6c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.5-1.1,0.8c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3c0.6,0.1,1.1,0.2,1.7,0.2   c1.9,0,3.8,0,5.6,0.1c1.1,0,1.3,0.3,0.8,1.3c-4.2,7-10.1,11.5-18.3,12.4c-5.9,0.7-11.9,1.1-17.8,1.7c-4.5,0.5-8.7,2-12.3,4.8   c-0.9,0.7-1.6,1.5-1.9,2.7c-0.5,2.3-1.9,3.9-4.3,4.2c-2.5,0.3-4.4-0.6-5.9-2.7c-0.7-1-1.6-1.8-2.6-2.5c-7.6-5.1-15.8-8.7-24.7-10.5   c-3.9-0.8-7.9-0.4-11.8,0.2c-2.4,0.4-4.9,0.6-7.4,0.8C153.7,259.9,153.3,259.9,152.5,259.9z M261.4,224.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2   c-1.1,0.7-2.2,1.5-3.4,2.2c-2.5,1.6-4.9,1.2-6.7-1.2c-1.3-1.6-2.8-2.8-4.7-3.5c-5-2-10.1-2.3-15.3-1.3c-8.1,1.6-13.4,6.6-16.8,13.8   c-3,6.3-4.6,13.1-5.6,20c-0.5,3.6-0.3,7,1.4,10.2c0.3,0.6,0.5,1.3,0.7,1.9c0.2,0.8,0.6,1,1.4,0.5c4.7-3.4,10.2-4.4,15.8-4.9   c4.9-0.5,9.8-0.8,14.7-1.2c7.3-0.7,12.8-4.2,16.3-10.7c0.6-1.1,0.5-1.3-0.8-1.4c-2.1-0.1-4.2-0.2-6.2-0.3c-0.8,0-1.5-0.2-2.3-0.3   c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0.5-0.3,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.8c1.2-0.6,2.4-1.2,3.6-1.9c2.5-1.5,4.8-3.3,6-6.2c0.4-0.9,0.5-1.8,0.8-2.9   c-2.7,0-5,1.6-7.8,1.2C256.8,232.9,261,229.7,261.4,224.3z M155.5,258.6c2.3-0.1,4.3-0.1,6.2-0.4c6.7-1.2,13.1-0.4,19.5,1.7   c5.9,2,11.4,4.7,16.8,7.8c1.2,0.7,1.2,0.5,1.5-0.7c0.4-2,0.8-4.1,1.6-6c0.5-1.2,0.8-2.4,0.6-3.7c-0.4-2.2-0.7-4.4-1.1-6.6   c-1.6-8.2-4.6-15.8-10.1-22.2c-3.7-4.4-8.5-7-14.3-7.2c-6.9-0.3-13,2-18.8,5.4c-0.7,0.4-1.2,1.4-1.6,2.2c-1,2.5-2.5,4.6-4.7,6.1   c-2.9,1.9-5.9,3.6-8.9,5.3c-0.5,0.3-1,0.6-1.7,1c1.6,0.8,2.8,1.5,4.1,2.1c2,0.9,4,1.5,6.2,1.3c1.1-0.1,2.1,0.1,3.2,0.1   c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c-1.3,1.6-2.7,3-4.9,3.5c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.5-1.1,0.8c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.8,1c2,1.1,4.2,1.5,6.5,1.1   c1.2-0.2,2.3-0.4,3.8-0.7c-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.3-0.6,1.8c-0.8,1.5-1.7,2.9-2.5,4.3C155.9,257.4,155.8,257.8,155.5,258.6z M152.5,209.1   c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.5,1.6,0.7c2.2,0.8,4.3,1.6,6.5,2.4c1.2,0.5,2.4,0.4,3.6-0.1c0.8-0.4,1.6-0.8,2.4-1.2   c2.4-1,3.6-2.9,4.3-5.3c1.6-5.5-0.6-10-6.2-11.1c-2.5-0.5-5.1-0.9-7.7-1.2c-2.5-0.3-5-0.5-7.5-0.8c-1.3-0.2-1.6,0-1.5,1.3   c0.5,4,1,8,3.8,11.2c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4c-0.6,0-1.2,0.1-1.9,0.1c0.5,1.6,2.1,1.7,3.3,2.6C153.1,208.7,152.8,208.9,152.5,209.1   z M252.6,205.8c0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7c2.7-3.3,3.3-7.2,3.6-11.2c0.1-1-0.2-1.3-1.2-1.1c-2.1,0.3-4.2,0.5-6.3,0.7   c-3.2,0.3-6.4,0.5-9.6,0.9c-3.2,0.4-5,2.6-5.8,5.6c-0.3,1,0,1.7,0.8,2.3c1.3,0.9,2.5,1.9,3.7,2.9c2,1.7,3.2,4.1,4.3,6.4   c0.3,0.7,0.7,1.1,1.6,0.8c2.2-0.8,4.5-1.5,6.7-2.2c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.4,1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8-0.9-1.1c1.1-0.9,2.8-0.8,3.3-2.4   C253.9,205.9,253.3,205.9,252.6,205.8z M203.4,223.3c0-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.1-0.8c0.3-0.9,0.5-1.9,1-2.7c0.2-0.2,1.3,0.1,1.9,0.2   c1.2,0.2,2.3,0.3,3.3-0.4c1-0.7,0.9-1.6-0.1-2.2c-1.3-0.8-2.8-1.1-4.2-0.4c-0.9,0.5-1.5,0.1-1.7-0.8c-0.2-0.6-0.2-1.4-0.1-2   c0.4-1.3,0.8-1.4,2.1-0.9c1,0.3,2.2,0.4,3.2,0.4c0.8,0,1.1-0.7,0.9-1.5c-0.3-1.1-1-1.7-2.2-1.6c-0.7,0-1.3,0.2-2,0.3   c-1.4,0.4-2,0.1-2.3-1.2c-0.2-0.8,0-1.8,0.3-2.6c0.2-0.6,0.7-0.7,1.2-0.2c0.6,0.6,1.3,1.1,1.9,1.6c1.1,0.9,1.7,0.8,2.5,0   c0.8-0.9,0.8-1.9-0.1-2.8c-0.9-0.9-2.1-1.6-3.4-1.2c-1.4,0.4-1.9-0.2-2.3-1.3c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.6-1.5c0.6,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.1   c0.5-0.1,1.1-0.3,1.4-0.7c0.2-0.2-0.1-0.9-0.3-1.2c-0.2-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.1-0.3c-1.1,0.7-1.4-0.1-1.9-0.9c0.6-0.1,1.1-0.2,1.6-0.2   c1,0,1.7-0.5,1.9-1.4c0.1-0.6,0-1.6-0.3-1.8c-0.6-0.3-1.4-0.2-2.1,0c-1,0.2-1.9,0.7-3,1.1c0.3,0.6,0.6,1.3,0.8,2   c0.3,0.9,0.6,1.7,0.8,2.6c0.3,1.2,0.5,2.4,0.9,3.5c0.3,0.7,0.4,1.2,0,1.9c-1,1.6-1,3.3,0,4.9c0.5,0.7,0.4,1.3,0,2   c-0.8,1.4-0.9,2.8,0.1,4.2c0.6,0.8,0.5,1.5,0.1,2.4c-0.4,1.1-0.6,2.2-0.8,3.3c-0.1,0.8-0.1,1.7-0.3,2.4c-0.3,1.5-0.5,2.9,0.2,4.4   c0.3,0.6,0.2,1.5,0,2.2c-0.8,2-0.5,3.9,0.5,5.8c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.3   c-0.7-1.5-1-3.1-0.4-4.7c0.3-0.8,0.6-1.2,1.5-0.9c0.5,0.2,1,0.2,1.5,0.1c0.9-0.1,1.3-0.8,1.3-1.6c0-0.8-0.6-1.2-1.4-1.1   c-0.4,0-0.9,0.1-1.3,0.2c-1.4,0.4-1.8,0.1-2-1.3c-0.1-0.5,0-1,0.1-1.5c0.1-0.8,0.6-1.1,1.5-0.9c1,0.3,2.1,0.4,3.2,0.5   c0.8,0.1,1.5-0.2,1.7-1c0.2-0.9,0-1.7-0.8-2c-0.8-0.3-1.7-0.5-2.6-0.5C204.9,222.7,204.2,223.1,203.4,223.3z M194.9,212.7   c1.2,0.5,2.2,1,3.1,1.2c1,0.2,1.5-0.5,1.9-1.3c0.3-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-2c-1.1-0.7-2.2-1-3.5-0.6c-0.4,0.1-1.1,0.1-1.2-0.2   c-0.8-1.3-1.1-2.7-0.7-4.3c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.6c1.5,0.6,3.3,0.2,4.2-0.9c0.5-0.6,0.5-1.2-0.4-1.4c-1.4-0.2-2.8-0.4-4.2-0.4   c-0.9,0-1.5-0.1-2-0.9c-0.8-1.3-0.8-2.6-0.1-3.9c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.5-1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.4-0.8,0.7   c-1.3,1.6-1.3,3.2,0.1,5.4c0.5,0.8,0.6,1.4,0.3,2.3c-0.5,1.4-0.3,2.9,0.5,4.1c0.7,1.2,0.8,2.5,0.7,3.8c-0.1,1.1-0.2,2.1-0.4,3.2   c-0.3,2.8-0.6,5.5,1.1,8c0.3,0.5,0.8,0.9,1.2,1.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.2c-1.1-2.1-2.6-4-1.9-6.7c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.3   c1.3,0.5,2.4,0.2,3.3-0.9c0.8-1,0.6-2-0.7-2.2c-0.8-0.1-1.7,0.1-2.6,0c-0.3,0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.6C194.7,214.9,194.8,213.8,194.9,212.7   z M215.4,221c-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.9-1.1-1.1c-1.2-0.7-1.4-1.8-1.2-3c0.1-0.9,0.6-1.3,1.5-1c0.9,0.2,1.8,0.5,2.7,0.6   c0.9,0.2,2.1-0.5,2.2-1.3c0.1-1-0.6-1.7-1.4-1.8c-1-0.1-2,0-3,0.2c-1.1,0.2-1.4,0.1-1.2-1.1c0.1-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.3   c0.8-0.5,1.6-1,2.5-1.2c1.3-0.4,2.1-1.2,2-2.4c-0.1-0.9-0.6-1.2-1.4-0.7c-0.6,0.4-1.2,0.9-1.8,1.4c-0.9,0.7-1.6,0.5-2.3-0.2   c-1.1-1.2-1.2-2.5-0.8-4c0.5-1.5,0.5-1.5,2-1.1c1.7,0.5,3.2,0.1,3.9-1.2c0.7-1.2,0.6-2.1-0.8-2.4c-0.9-0.2-2,0-3,0.2   c-0.6,0.1-1.1,0.7-1.7,1c-1.4-1.4-0.4-3-0.4-4.5c-1.2,0.8-1.9,2.4-1.3,3.3c1.1,1.8,0.7,3.5,0.2,5.3c-0.5,1.8,0,3.3,1.7,4.4   c0.7,0.5,0.7,1,0.4,1.7c-0.4,0.9-0.5,1.9-0.7,2.8c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.5-0.3,2.2C211.6,218.5,212.4,220.3,215.4,221z M185.9,218.8   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3c-0.4-0.8-1-1.6-1.3-2.5c-0.4-1-0.8-2-0.8-3c0-1.2,0.5-1.4,1.7-1c0.5,0.1,1,0.4,1.5,0.4   c0.8,0,1.6,0.1,2.3-0.3c0.4-0.2,0.8-1,0.8-1.5c0-0.3-0.8-0.7-1.3-0.8c-1.2,0-2.4,0.1-3.6,0.2c-0.8,0.1-1.3-0.2-1.6-0.9   c-0.4-1-0.7-2,0.2-2.8c0.5-0.4,1.3-0.6,2-0.6c0.6,0,1.3,0.4,1.9,0.7c1.1,0.6,2.8-0.3,3.3-1.5c0.4-0.9,0.1-1.4-0.9-1.4   c-1,0-1.9,0.1-2.9,0.3c-1.9,0.2-2.1,0.1-2.7-1.6c-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2c-0.1-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.6-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1   c0,0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1.1c0.2,0.7,0.4,1.5,0.8,2.1c0.4,0.8,0.3,1.3-0.4,2c-1.2,1.1-1.6,2.5-0.9,3.9c0.6,1.1,1.1,2.1,0.2,3.2   c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.7-0.1,1.1C183.8,215.4,184.9,217.1,185.9,218.8z M232.1,216c0.7-0.8,1.5-0.2,2.3,0.2c1.3,0.6,2.5,0.3,3.6-0.5   c0.7-0.5,0.7-1.2,0.1-1.8c-1.1-1.1-3.1-1.4-4.5-0.6c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.2c-0.6-0.2-1.2-2.1-1-2.9c0.3-0.9,1-1.2,2.1-0.9   c0.9,0.2,1.8,0.6,2.7,0.6c0.5,0,1.3-0.4,1.5-0.9c0.2-0.4-0.1-1.3-0.4-1.7c-0.7-0.9-2.2-1-3.6-0.3c-1.2,0.6-1.7,0.5-2.2-0.8   c-0.2-0.7-0.1-1.5-0.2-2.2c0-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.5c-1.1,1.3-1.4,2.9-0.6,4.1c0.7,1.1,0.7,1.9,0.1,3.1c-0.4,0.7-0.3,1.9-0.1,2.8   C231.1,213.8,231.7,214.9,232.1,216z M229.2,216c-0.1-2.1-1.2-2.9-3.1-2.4c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2c-1.5,0.6-2.3,0.2-3-1.3   c-0.8-2-0.2-2.9,1.9-3.2c0.5-0.1,1.1-0.2,1.6-0.5c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.7,0.5-1.1c0-0.2-0.6-0.5-0.9-0.5c-0.7,0-1.4,0-2,0.2   c-1.7,0.4-2.3-0.2-1.8-1.9c0.1-0.5,0.6-0.9,1-1.3c0.7-0.6,1.5-1,2.2-1.6c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.8c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8,0   c-0.9,0.6-1.9,1.2-2.7,2c-1.5,1.3-1.5,2.3-0.6,4c0.3,0.6,0.6,1.5,0.5,2.1c-0.5,2,0.1,3.7,1.7,4.9C225,216.2,227,216.4,229.2,216z    M178.4,203.2c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3c-1.6,0.8-3.3,1.5-4.1,3.2c-0.4,0.8-0.2,1.8-0.1,2.7c0.1,1.1,0.5,2.1,0.5,3.2   c0,2.8,1.1,4.3,3.7,5.1c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.2,1.6,0.4c1,0.4,1.8,0.1,2.5-0.5c-0.8-2-1.1-2.2-3.1-1.9c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.3-1.3,0.3   c-0.4,0-0.9,0.1-1.2-0.2c-1-0.8-1.6-1.9-1.4-3.3c0.1-0.8,0.5-1.2,1.3-1.2c0.7,0,1.5-0.2,2.2-0.5c0.3-0.1,0.7-0.8,0.6-1.1   c-0.1-0.3-0.6-0.8-1-0.8c-0.7,0-1.5,0.2-2.2,0.4c-1.2,0.3-1.8,0-1.7-1.3c0.1-0.7,0.5-1.4,1-1.9c0.6-0.6,1.4-1,2.1-1.5   C178,203.8,178.2,203.5,178.4,203.2z M166.6,213.2c0.6,2.2,1.2,4.4,1.9,6.9c0.3-0.8,0.4-1.2,0.6-1.8c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.3,1.1,0.2   c0.6-0.1,1.1-0.4,1.6-0.7c0.1-0.1,0-0.7-0.2-0.8c-0.5-0.3-1-0.5-1.5-0.6c-0.2-0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.2c-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.3-1-0.5   c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2c0.8-0.2,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.6c1-0.5,1.2-1.5,0.7-2.5c-0.5-0.9-1.3-0.7-2-0.4   C168.8,212.2,167.7,212.8,166.6,213.2z M205,272.2c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3c-1.8-2-2.6-4.3-2.7-7c0-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5-1   C200.2,268.1,201.8,272.2,205,272.2z"
       id="path9" /><path
       class="st0"
       d="M261.4,224.3c-0.4,5.4-4.6,8.6-7.9,12.6c2.8,0.4,5-1.1,7.8-1.2c-0.3,1-0.4,2-0.8,2.9c-1.2,2.8-3.5,4.6-6,6.2   c-1.2,0.7-2.4,1.3-3.6,1.9c-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.8c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0.8,0.1,1.5,0.3,2.3,0.3c2.1,0.1,4.2,0.2,6.2,0.3   c1.3,0.1,1.4,0.3,0.8,1.4c-3.6,6.4-9.1,10-16.3,10.7c-4.9,0.5-9.8,0.7-14.7,1.2c-5.6,0.6-11.1,1.6-15.8,4.9   c-0.8,0.5-1.1,0.3-1.4-0.5c-0.2-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.7-1.9c-1.7-3.2-1.9-6.6-1.4-10.2c1-6.9,2.6-13.6,5.6-20c3.4-7.2,8.7-12.2,16.8-13.8   c5.2-1,10.3-0.7,15.3,1.3c1.9,0.8,3.5,1.9,4.7,3.5c1.9,2.4,4.2,2.8,6.7,1.2c1.1-0.7,2.3-1.5,3.4-2.2   C261.2,224.1,261.3,224.2,261.4,224.3z M235.2,222.2c-5,0.2-9.6,1.6-13.5,4.9c-5.3,4.5-8.1,10.4-10,16.8c-0.2,0.8,0.2,1.1,0.9,1.3   c0.6,0.2,1.2,0.3,1.5-0.6c0.6-1.7,1.2-3.5,1.9-5.1c2-4.7,4.7-8.9,9.1-11.8c5.7-3.7,11.8-3.8,18-1.6c0.8,0.3,1.5,0.5,1.8-0.5   c0.3-0.9-0.1-1.4-1-1.7C241.1,222.8,238.2,222.2,235.2,222.2z M236.4,237.8c0-2.1-0.9-4.5-2.2-6.1c-2.5-3-6.1-2.9-8.4,0.2   c-2,2.7-2.1,5.6-0.7,8.6c1.4,2.9,3.6,3.9,6.8,3.2C234.7,243,236.4,240.8,236.4,237.8z"
       id="path11" /><path
       class="st0"
       d="M155.5,258.6c0.3-0.7,0.4-1.2,0.6-1.6c0.8-1.5,1.7-2.9,2.5-4.3c0.3-0.5,0.4-1,0.6-1.8   c-1.5,0.3-2.6,0.5-3.8,0.7c-2.3,0.4-4.5,0-6.5-1.1c-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.7-0.8-1c0.4-0.3,0.7-0.7,1.1-0.8c2.2-0.5,3.6-1.9,4.9-3.5   c0-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4c-1.1,0-2.2-0.2-3.2-0.1c-2.2,0.2-4.3-0.3-6.2-1.3c-1.3-0.6-2.5-1.3-4.1-2.1c0.8-0.4,1.2-0.7,1.7-1   c3-1.8,6-3.4,8.9-5.3c2.2-1.5,3.6-3.6,4.7-6.1c0.3-0.8,0.9-1.8,1.6-2.2c5.8-3.4,11.9-5.7,18.8-5.4c5.9,0.3,10.6,2.8,14.3,7.2   c5.5,6.4,8.5,14,10.1,22.2c0.4,2.2,0.7,4.4,1.1,6.6c0.2,1.3-0.1,2.4-0.6,3.7c-0.8,1.9-1.2,3.9-1.6,6c-0.3,1.3-0.3,1.4-1.5,0.7   c-5.4-3.1-10.9-5.9-16.8-7.8c-6.4-2.1-12.8-2.9-19.5-1.7C159.8,258.5,157.8,258.4,155.5,258.6z M195.8,245.5   c1.5-0.1,2.1-0.7,1.7-1.7c-1.1-2.8-2.1-5.7-3.5-8.4c-6-11.4-17.1-15.7-29-11.2c-1.3,0.5-1.4,0.9-0.9,2c0.4,0.9,1,0.5,1.6,0.3   c3.8-1.4,7.8-2.1,11.9-1.3c5.9,1.1,10.2,4.6,13.1,9.6c1.8,3,3,6.3,4.4,9.5C195.3,244.8,195.6,245.2,195.8,245.5z M170.8,237.9   c0,3.2,1.1,4.8,3.8,5.8c2.5,1,4.8,0.4,6.5-1.5c2.6-2.9,2.4-8.4-0.5-11c-2.2-2-5-2.1-7-0.1C171.8,233,170.7,235.2,170.8,237.9z"
       id="path13" />
```

A tool I'm using to render SVG images on a webpage requires a single path. I'm able to generate one using Inkscape by just tracing a Bitmap and saving it as SVG, but I can not do the same in Illustrator. I've tried using the same settings as on that other question linked above, but it still gives me multiple paths.

Example of what I need:

```
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M100,0 C155.228476,-3.41060513e-14 200,44.771524 200,100 C200,155.228476 155.228476,200 100,200 C44.771524,200 0,155.228476 0,100 C0,44.771524 44.771524,3.03201907e-14 100,0 Z M40.0135555,79.4855784 L40.0135555,102.780614 C55.2214198,102.790103 69.6051125,108.763989 80.3694989,119.544636 C91.1311742,130.291394 97.0806631,144.696768 97.1050629,159.95749 L97.1131962,159.95749 L97.1131962,159.999512 L120.504488,159.999512 C120.485511,137.809245 111.465711,117.709228 96.8827535,103.115434 C82.2970845,88.5243505 62.2051899,79.4991339 40.0135555,79.4855784 Z M44.7525423,155.112773 L44.7471201,155.112773 L44.7525423,155.118195 L44.7525423,155.112773 C47.7008537,158.048883 51.7200459,159.849046 56.1947014,159.849046 C60.6747791,159.849046 64.7034602,158.054305 67.6531271,155.118195 L67.6639714,155.112773 C70.6082161,152.172597 72.4056694,148.168318 72.4165138,143.718064 C72.4056694,139.259678 70.6082161,135.255399 67.6531271,132.304378 L67.6585492,132.304378 L67.6531271,132.300311 L67.6531271,132.304378 C64.6993935,129.369624 60.6747791,127.55726 56.1947014,127.55726 C51.7214015,127.55726 47.7022092,129.365557 44.7525423,132.304378 L44.7525423,132.300311 C41.8110087,135.24591 40,139.259678 40,143.718064 C40,148.17374 41.8110087,152.173952 44.7525423,155.112773 Z M40.0555774,62.9029686 C93.5271714,62.9416349 136.994841,106.477281 137.030841,159.999512 L160,159.999512 C159.984,126.919781 146.538769,96.9493582 124.809601,75.2055351 C103.073766,53.4683787 73.1233263,40.0151548 40.0555774,40.0004883 Z M40.0555774,62.9029686" fill="#444444"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Notice the single `path d=`.

Is there a way to generate this in Illustrator? Or do I need to continue using Inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered me on another forum, so I'll put the answer here as well in case anyone else is looking in the future.

```
Creating a compound path should output a single path within your SVG code.
Select your elements and then Object → Compound Path → Make.
```

Keep in mind this requires your entire SVG to be just one color.